# can we use multiple models in single controller in slim framework

Tags: php, slim

```
 $this->app->post('/tech-master/stores/config/add', array($this, 'defaultConfig'));
        $this->app->get('/tech-master/stores/config/edit/:userId', array($this, 'editConfigById'));
        // Created obj of Users model
        $this->userObj = new Users();
        $this->storeObj = new Stores();
    }
```

how to use multiple models in the single controller for the slim framework

Comment: Could you format your code and elaborate on what your asking helpt with?

Comment: I have not worked in Slim before but can't you just `use AsManyModels;` as you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Slim doesn't care what you do in you route callable.